# Calculating covariance (PCA example)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

What is $z_1$? We have $n$ observations of $p$ different quantities (variables). It's defined on page 6. Is it just a projection onto the vector $a_1$? $a_1$ is our new basis vector and thus $z_1$ is the first coefficient in the new basis - is that correct?
$z_1$ is the first coefficient in the new basis, and we re-express all $n$ vectors using this new basis.

$var[z_1]$ is the variance that occurs in the set of $n$ observations of the first quantity (I guess). The question regarding page 8 (presented below):

**1)** Why is $var[z_1]$ calculated that way?

**2)** Why is it equal to dot product of $z_{1}^2$ minus squared dot product of $z_1$? What does the dot product mean in this case? Or is it just the expected value defined to be an inner product? It looks the same as variance of random variable $X$ expressed in terms of the expected value, i.e. $\mathbb{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2$. I'm not sure why expected value of a single random variable $X$ is expressed as a dot product here (what's the meaning of dot product of random variable? A dot product can be calculated given we have two vectors. Here we neither have two, or vectors, so to speak.

**3)** Is it the length of a vector made of all $z_1$ components of vectors in the data set?

Could you explain it in the simplest possible terms? I don't quite understand the next steps from page 8 (screen 1).

[image]

Explanation of what those symbols mean (pages 6,7). [Source](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.pdf)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the definition for the notation : <,> ? You have mentioned it as cross product, but I feel it's better to clearly mention what this means.

Comment: I meant dot product.

Comment: What is meant by $z_1^2$? Can you please expand this out ?

Comment: Well, it's here: http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.pdf I said it's better if you check in the document. (pages 6,7,8)

Comment: This is a good reference :https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_sym_pca.html

Comment: I'm asking about this particular derivation of variance.

Comment: I suggest this post to be moved to cross validation stackexchange instead.

Comment: I've edited the question. The first line on the first picture resembles the definition of variance in terms of the expected value. No idea why we are using dot product here. Dot product can work if we have exactly two vectors. Is it just that the vector is the set of values the random variable has taken in this example? And we are calculating the dot product of that vector with itself? Anwyay, I don't see how calculating dot product is related to expected value.